# fetching a custom object from core data into an array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, fetch

I'm having trouble fetching my object from core data. Object looks like this:

```
class cilj: NSObject {
var imeCilja: String
var slikaCilja: String }
```

My entity is called Entity and has two Attributes "tekst" and "slika", both of type String. My save func is this:

```
func saveImage(goalName:String, imageName:String) {

  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entityDescription =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entity", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    let thingToSaveToCD = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    thingToSaveToCD.setValue(globalGoalTitle, forKey: "tekst")
    thingToSaveToCD.setValue(globalGoalImagePath, forKey: "slika")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        print("managed to save to core data")
        //5
       // listaObjekata.append(cilj5) as! [cilj]
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

I use an alertController to pick up the text, and imagePicker to pick up image that I then store in documents and get the path. I store both of these in a global variables visible in the code above.

My fetch function is :

```
func coreDataFetch(){

    //core data fetch

    //1
    let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")


    do {
        let fetchedResults =  try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [cilj]
        listaObjekata = fetchedResults


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

I have been through ray wenderlich's article on Core Data, Apple's documentation, a couple of YT videos but I still seem to be missing something. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks !

EDIT - here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! cellController
    let ciljZaPrikaz = listaObjekata[indexPath.item]

    cell.labelText.text = ciljZaPrikaz.imeCilja ?? "no text found"

    let path = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(ciljZaPrikaz.slikaCilja)
    cell.imageToShow.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? `let fetchedResults =  try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Entity]`

Comment: Hey, yes I have and then it says on the line below it "Cannot assign a value of type [Entity] to type [cilj].

Comment: You are saving with `Entity` and fetching with `Entity` then why the array is `[cilj]`?. Just try to print the `fetchedResults` and check what you are getting. Remove `as! [Entity]` or `as! [cilj]` and try.

Comment: I've tried it and when I enter a text and and an image I get
    [<Entity: 0x7fdffad0fe60> (entity: Entity; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://ACEC5EBD-13BF-486E-BED3-65562FEFCD73/Entity/p1> ; data: <fault>)]

Comment: Yes, thats the data you are getting back from CoreData. you should cast it to your entity class. `let enityModel = fetchedResults[0] as? Entity`. Then you can access the value like `entityModel. tekst`

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you ! I managed to get my data ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Thats a great news! I will add this to answer, please upvote/mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing correct but just missing type casting to your model. Try below:

```
    let fetchedResults =  try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    if let results = fetchResults where results.count > 0 {
        let entityModel = results[0] as? Entity
        let tekst = entityModel.tekst
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add how I iterate through my return objects from core data:

```
 do {
        let fetchedResults =  try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
         listaObjekata.removeAll()
        for i in 0...(fetchedResults.count-1) {
             let enityModel = fetchedResults[i] as? Entity

                let thisToArray = cilj(imeCilja: (enityModel?.tekst!)!, slikaCilja: (enityModel?.slika!)!)
                listaObjekata.append(thisToArray)

        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```